# How to redirect public to non public URL with .htaccess?

Tags: laravel, .htaccess, redirect, public, shared

I have app developed in Laravel and hosted in shared hosting. 
Due to some issue my app is also working with www.example.com/public/url which I don't want. 
Many of my website pages are index with folder public as well as non public. Is there any solution that I can use in .htaccess to redirect 301 to non public URL. I have tried many solutions but nothing worked for me.
If I use redirect with specific URL it works for that URL but I want to redirect all public to non public URL.

Comment: Do you have SSH access?

Comment: You should point the domain at the public folder and not the root directory of your app.